# Discovering indirect shared followers

Tags: twitter, social-graph

On Twitter, given a list of followers, is there a way to see indirect shared followers and group them based on the number of followers that follow said Twitter user.

**For example,**

- My Followers: Abe, Bob, Cathy, Dave, Ed

  - Abe Followers: a001, a002, a003
  - Bob Followers: a001, b001, b002
  - Cathy Followers: a001, b001, c001
  - Dave Followers: a001, b001, c001, d001
  - Ed Followers: a001, b001, c001, d001, e001

**Results of indirect shared followers:**

- a001 = Abe, Bob, Cathy, Dave, Ed (count 5)
- b001 = Bob, Cathy, Dave, Ed (count 4)
- c001 = Cathy, Dave, Ed (count 3)
- d001 = Dave, Ed (count 2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible but not through Twitter UI. The solution would need programming and maybe a directed graph to keep track of the connections.

Comment: This is possible. I have done it. You will run into limits when the number of followers is large. Or if a popular account follows you.

Comment: He didn't say it was impossible. He just said you couldn't do it through the UI that Twitter has. Through the API, yes, but not the UI.